# what is the shortest way to check for typeof any type?

Tags: javascript

I found this today to check if something is a boolean:

Instead of:

```
typeof a === 'boolean' && //do sth
```

You can use:

```
a === !!a && //do sth
```

Are there any other methods like this to check for `typeof string/number/obj/arr` etc?

I'm not looking for best practices but rather for clever ways to do " typechecking "  .

Comment: Why on earth would you reinvent `typeof`?

Comment: The most clever way would be to write idiomatic, widely understood and intended code. But I guess it depends on your definition of sanity.

Comment: @IngoBürk - Or cleverness.

Answer (score 5):

Types in javascript are not that simple but [this](http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/) is a great guide for you!

Checking types in Javascript is a big mess.

> typeof operator
>
> In the beginning, there was typeof. This handy operator gives you the
>   "type" of a Javascript value:

```
typeof 3 // "number" 
typeof "abc" // "string"
 typeof {} // "object"
 typeof true // "boolean" 
typeof undefined // "undefined" 
typeof function(){} // "function"
```

> All is fine 'n dandy until

```
typeof [] // "object"
```

> Huh? An array's type is object? I guess it is, if you want to get
>   technical about it, but still, what the...

```
typeof null // "object"
```

> Okay, now that's just wrong!
>
> instanceof operator
>
> The instanceof operator tells you whether a object
>   is an instance of a certain type. The so-called "type" is a
>   constructor. For example

```
function Animal(){}
    var a = new Animal()
    a instanceof Animal // true
```

> Cross-window Issues of instanceof
>
> It turns out that instanceof has another problem. It breaks down when
>   you try to test an object coming from another window. You know? The
>   ones that are created for each ,  or popup window that
>   you create.

```
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)
    var iWindow = iframe.contentWindow // get a reference to the window object of the iframe
    iWindow.document.write('<script>var arr = [1, 2, 3]</script>') // create an array var in iframe's window
    iWindow.arr // [1, 2, 3]
    iWindow.arr instanceof Array // false
```

> Duck-Typing
>
> Because neither typeof or instanceof are satisfactory, many resort to
>   duck-typing. This means checking the behavior: if it looks like a duck
>   and quacks like a duck, then it is a duck as far as I am concerned.
>   Pretty sure I misquoted that...oh well.
>
> So, using duck-typing, an isArray check might look like

```
// source: http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/javascript-test-whether-a-variable-is-array-or-not-33051.html
function isArray(obj){
    return (typeof(obj.length)=="undefined") ?
        false:true;
}
```

> Object.prototype.toString method
>
> It turns out that, you can get type information about an object by
>   using the Object.prototype.toString method.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(3) // "[object Number]"
Object.prototype.toString.call([1, 2, 3]) // "[object Array]"
Object.prototype.toString.call({}) // "[object Object]"
```

> Function.prototype.toString method
>
> Yet another way to test for type information is by using the
>   Function.prototype.toString method.

```
Function.prototype.toString.call((3).constructor)
// "function Number() {
//    [native code]
// }"
```

> DOM Elements and Host Objects
>
> So far, I have not mentioned type checking for DOM elements and host
>   objects. That's because it's hard. With the exception of duck-typing,
>   none of the methods mentioned above will work for all browsers. If you
>   drop IE7 and below, however, you can actually get some of the things
>   to work. The output below were created using Tutti

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
typeof div
Safari 5.0 => object
Firefox 3.6 => object
IE 7.0 => object
IE 8.0 => object
Opera 11.01 => object
div instanceof Element
Safari 5.0 => true
Firefox 3.6 => true
IE 7.0 => Error: 'Element' is undefined
IE 8.0 => true
Opera 11.01 => true
div instanceof HTMLDivElement
Safari 5.0 => true
Firefox 3.6 => true
IE 8.0 => true
IE 7.0 => Error: 'HTMLDivElement' is undefined
Opera 11.01 => true
```

http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

A very similar concept applies to all the fundamental types, but involving a function call and possibly more work than just boolean negation like your boolean example:

```
// String
a === String(a)

// Number
n === +n  // **FAILS** if `a` is `NaN` (which is `typeof "number"`)
Object.is(n, +n) // Works even if it is, but 0 and -0 are considered different

// Object (including arrays)
o === Object(o)
```

That last works because `Object` returns the object you call it with, if you call it with an object (it doesn't create a new one).

---

I know you've said you're intersted in tricks and not best practices, but...in general, I wouldn't do the above. I'd use `typeof` if I cared about the type and didn't know what it was, or conversion if I wanted a specific destination type and didn't know what type the input was.

Comment: If I ever see `Object.is(n, +n)` in any code of even lesser significance, there will be coffee mugs flying.

Comment: @PaulStenne - With you there. :-D

Answer (score 0):

## A clean approach

You can't do it cleanly. Javascript has a few quirks that I see almost always throws people off, even the most experience. And very often you end up with very ugly, not really human readable conditional statements:

```js
if (
    typeof foo !== 'string'
    || (typeof foo !== 'number'
    || (typeof foo === 'number' && !isNaN(chk)))
    || !Array.isArray(chk)
) {

    throw Error("Not valid, but I don't know why.")
}
```

### No other way, just use a very lightweight library

You should consider using a very small library like [Issable](https://github.com/calvintwr/issable). Solves all problems:

```js
let integer = 10
let array = []
is(integer).number() // returns true
is(array).number() // throws error
```

If you make it a habit, your code will be much stronger. Typescript solves part of the problem but doesn't work at runtime, which is also important.

```js
function test (string, boolean) {
    // any of these below will throw errors to protect you
    is(string).string()
    is(boolean).boolean()
    // continue with your code.
}
```